# Sum numbers in range of cells containing both numbers and letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are a range of cells for which I only want to sum the numbers:

Example:

```
TPR4    TPR6    REP6    REP2/TPR6   TPR22    44
```

**Please note** a few cells are BLANKS, and the last cell should be a sum of all the END numbers i.e. 4,6,6,6,22 in above example

Can anyone please advise on a formula?

Comment: Thanks Guys for answering! there's now a bit of additional variation to my initial question, please see additional details

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you sample set is in a row 1 and that the numeric portion is always at the end or all of the string:

```
// copy this to the right under all of your data cells
B2: =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)
```

The sum of these row will then give you the answer you seek:

```
=SUM(A2:D2)
```

Comment: did you test that? And what is "row A" in your universe?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Row A is the data.

Comment: Excel does not have a Row A.

Comment: Row 1. Edited. Note the MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789") finds the position of the first integer. The rest of the formula then uses this location to extract the number portion. Thus TPR4 returns 4, 16 returns 16, T22 returns 22, etc. These cells can then be summed. @teylyn Thanks for the row A catch.

Comment: Cool stuff, this would have nailed it if OP didn't change the original question.

Comment: I'd not realized the question had changed until you posted that comment yesterday. Thank you. I just posted an answer to the revised question.

Answer (score 0):

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-3)+RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-3)` would work for your example.

Does it need to be any more complex than that?

Answer (score 0):

You changed the question a touch, so I am adding another answer (to the revised question).

Assuming you sample set is in a row 1, cells A1 to E1, and that the numeric portion is always at the end or all of the string:

```
// copy this to the right under all of your data cells
Cell A2: =IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1))&"0123456789"))+1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1))+0
// Then, sum up in F2:
Cell F2: =SUM(A2:E2)
```

If you wanted to get instead get the sum of the ending number in both strings where separated by a "/", for example where the string is REP2/TPR6 return 8 instead of 6, then:

```
// copy this to the right under all of your data cells
Cell A2: =IFERROR(MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),FIND("/",A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")))  +  RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("/",A1)+MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1))&"0123456789")))+1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)+0)
// Then, sum up in F2:
Cell F2: =SUM(A2:E2)
```

Tested these. Should work. Allows alpha portion to be any length.